# How can I kill processes when parental time limits expire?

Tags: macos, parental-controls

My children routinely leave CPU hogging processes (usually flash games) running on our shared computer when they run out of computer time for the day, or when they are very close to running out of computer time for the day.

Is there a way I can automatically have all their processes killed when their account is no longer using the console?